# twice nested form path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-attributes

i have the following form for my user_calendar model:

```
<%= form_for([company,user,calendar], :remote => true) do |f| %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

route is the following:

```
scope '(:locale)' do
  resources :companies do
    resources :users do
      resources :user_calendar
    end
  end
end
```

When user clicks Edit on users/home:

```
<%= link_to 'E', edit_company_user_path(user.company, user), :remote => true %>
```

The method is called from users_controller:

```
def edit
  @calendar = @user.user_calendars.build
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And edit.js should load the models data for the form:

```
$('#calendar-form').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'user_calendars/form', :locals => { :company => @company, :user => @user, :calendar => @calendar }) %>");
```

But instead of rendering the form i get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `company_user_user_calendars_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc351d12808>:0x00000001cf6128>):
```

The three @company, @user and @calendar have the right data, but still the path shows the error. Here the result of rake routes on user_calendars controller:

```
Controller#Action
company_user_user_calendar_index GET    (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar(.:format)          user_calendar#index
                             POST   (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar(.:format)          user_calendar#create
  new_company_user_user_calendar GET    (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar/new(.:format)      user_calendar#new
 edit_company_user_user_calendar GET    (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar/:id/edit(.:format) user_calendar#edit
  company_user_user_calendar GET    (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar/:id(.:format)      user_calendar#show
                             PATCH  (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar/:id(.:format)      user_calendar#update
                             PUT    (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar/:id(.:format)      user_calendar#update
                             DELETE (/:locale)/companies/:company_id/users/:user_id/user_calendar/:id(.:format)      user_calendar#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could happens because of: `resources :user_calendar`

if you need `resources` you should write `resources :user_calendars` - with (`s`)

also you could look to guid about [resources/resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)